# Sparklyr/Dplyr - How to apply a user defined function for each row of a sparkdata frame and create write the output of each row to new column?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

I have a spark_tbl containing 160+ columns.

I will give an example to show how the dataframe looks:

```
Key  A  B  C  D  E  F  G .....Z

s1   0  1  0  1  1  0  1      0
s2   1  0  0  0  0  0  0      0
s3   1  1  0  0  0  0  0      0
s4   0  1  0  1  1  0  0      0
```

What I want to achieve is to create a new column based on the values is each column like,

```
Key  A  B  C  D  E  F  G .....Z  panel

s1   0  1  0  1  1  0  1      0  B,D,E,G
s2   1  0  0  0  0  0  0      0  A 
s3   1  1  0  0  0  0  0      0  A,B
s4   0  1  0  1  1  0  0      0  B,D,E
```

Check each column rowwise and add the column name to the string if the value is 1 and finally write it to a column called panel.

My attempt at writing a user defined function:

```
get_panel <- function(eachrow){
 id <- ""
 row_list <- as.list(eachrow)
 for (i in 1:length(row_list)){
  if(row_list[i] == "1"){
   if(id == ""){
     id = columns[i+1]
   }else{
     id = paste(id, ",", columns[i+1])
   }
  }
 }
return(id)
}
```

This works with regular dataframe using apply function.
But,

How to apply this function to Spark Dataframe or tbl_spark?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `spark_apply`?

Comment: @hdkrgr
I tried using it but couldn't figure out how to pass each row as an argument using spark_apply and create a new column using output of the function.

Here was my attempt at it, but failed.
                        df$panel = spark_apply(df, get_panel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that @JasonAizkalns is on the right track. Starting with his example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")


mat <- matrix(c(paste0("s", 1:4), as.numeric(sample(0:1, 4 * 26, TRUE))), ncol = 27)
colnames(mat) <- c("Key", LETTERS[1:26])

df <- data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-"Key"), as.numeric) %>%
  as_data_frame()
df

dfs <- copy_to(sc, df, overwrite = TRUE)
```

We can get there using a little `rlang` magic.

```
dfs <- dfs %>% mutate(panel = "")
for (letter in LETTERS[1:26]) {
  dfs <- dfs %>% mutate(panel = concat_ws(",", panel, ifelse(!!sym(letter) == 1.0, yes = letter, no = NA)))
}

dfs %>% 
  mutate(panel = regexp_replace(panel, "^,", "")) %>% # remove leading comma
  select(Key, A:D, panel)
```

Gives what I think you want

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 6]
  Key       A     B     C     D panel                           
* <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                           
1 s1        0     0     1     1 C,D,E,G,O,P,Q,U,Z              
2 s2        1     0     0     1 A,D,G,K,L,M,N,Q,S,U,W          
3 s3        0     1     0     0 B,E,L,M,O,Q,R,S,T,Y            
4 s4        1     1     0     1 A,B,D,E,G,I,J,M,N,R,S,T,U,V,Y,Z
```

The key here is the `concat_ws` Spark SQL (not R) function. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#concat_ws-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-

Comment: I thought of doing this but there are around 160 columns and the size of the data frame would drastically increase if we create duplicate columns. Also this works for 4 columns but when we have 160 columns it would  not be optimal to write all the column names in concat function.

Comment: I've edited my answer to not modify existing columns and build the `panel` variable in a loop. I don't think that for-loop vs. lapply or similar matters here because the for loop is merely appending operations to be done lazily later, and computation happens when I print it

Comment: Throws the following error : **Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`key`' given input columns.** And i have not removed the key column its there in dfs .

Comment: In this example it is `Key`, not `key`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will translate 100% to `sparklyr`, but you may be able to use `sdf_nest`:

```
library(tidyverse)

mat <- matrix(c(paste0("s", 1:4), as.numeric(sample(0:1, 4 * 26, TRUE))), ncol = 27)
colnames(mat) <- c("Key", LETTERS[1:26])

df <- data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-"Key"), as.numeric) %>%
  as_data_frame()
df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 27
#>   Key       A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J     K
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 s1        0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1
#> 2 s2        0     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0
#> 3 s3        0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1
#> 4 s4        0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     1
#> # ... with 15 more variables: L <dbl>, M <dbl>, N <dbl>, O <dbl>, P <dbl>,
#> #   Q <dbl>, R <dbl>, S <dbl>, T <dbl>, U <dbl>, V <dbl>, W <dbl>,
#> #   X <dbl>, Y <dbl>, Z <dbl>

df %>%
  group_by(Key) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(panel = map_chr(data, ~ unlist(.) %>% as.logical %>% names(df)[-1][.] %>% paste(collapse = ",")))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Key   data              panel                           
#>   <chr> <list>            <chr>                          
#> 1 s1    <tibble [1 x 26]> B,C,D,E,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,W,Y,Z
#> 2 s2    <tibble [1 x 26]> B,D,F,G,H,I,N,R,S,T,V,W,X,Z    
#> 3 s3    <tibble [1 x 26]> B,C,D,E,J,K,M,N,O,Q,R,S,T,V,X,Y
#> 4 s4    <tibble [1 x 26]> D,H,I,K,L,O,P,T,U,V,W,Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this scala solution.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("s1",0,1,0,1,1,0,1),
     | ("s2",1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
     | ("s3",1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
     | ("s4",0,1,0,1,1,0,0)).toDF("key","A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, A: int ... 6 more fields]

scala> df.show
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|key|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|  F|  G|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| s1|  0|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|
| s2|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
| s3|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
| s4|  0|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

scala> val columns = df.columns.filter(x=>x != "key")
columns: Array[String] = Array(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)

scala> val p1 = columns.map( x => when(col(x)===lit(1),x+",").otherwise(lit(""))).reduce(concat(_,_)).as("panel")
p1: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(CASE WHEN (A = 1) THEN A, ELSE  END, CASE WHEN (B = 1) THEN B, ELSE  END), CASE WHEN (C = 1) THEN C, ELSE  END), CASE WHEN (D = 1) THEN D, ELSE  END), CASE WHEN (E = 1) THEN E, ELSE  END), CASE WHEN (F = 1) THEN F, ELSE  END), CASE WHEN (G = 1) THEN G, ELSE  END) AS `panel`

scala> df.select(p1).show(false)
+--------+
|panel   |
+--------+
|B,D,E,G,|
|A,      |
|A,B,    |
|B,D,E,  |
+--------+
```

With all columns,

```
scala> df.select(col("*"), p1).show
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--------+
|key|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|  F|  G|   panel|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--------+
| s1|  0|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|B,D,E,G,|
| s2|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|      A,|
| s3|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|    A,B,|
| s4|  0|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|  0|  B,D,E,|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--------+
```

There is a trailing comma in the result. That can be removed by

```
scala> df.select(col("*"), regexp_replace(p1,",$","").as("panel")).show
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------+
|key|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|  F|  G|  panel|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------+
| s1|  0|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|B,D,E,G|
| s2|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|      A|
| s3|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|    A,B|
| s4|  0|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|  0|  B,D,E|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-------+


scala>
```

**EDIT2:**

```
A more cleaner approach would be to use just array() function with concat_ws

scala> val df = Seq(("s1",0,1,0,1,1,0,1),("s2",1,0,0,0,0,0,0),("s3",1,1,0,0,0,0,0),("s4",0,1,0,1,1,0,0)).toDF("key","A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [key: string, A: int ... 6 more fields]

scala> df.show(false)
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|key|A  |B  |C  |D  |E  |F  |G  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|s1 |0  |1  |0  |1  |1  |0  |1  |
|s2 |1  |0  |0  |0  |0  |0  |0  |
|s3 |1  |1  |0  |0  |0  |0  |0  |
|s4 |0  |1  |0  |1  |1  |0  |0  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+


scala> val p1 = columns.map( x => when(col(x)===lit(1),x).otherwise(null))
p1: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(CASE WHEN (A = 1) THEN A ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN (B = 1) THEN B ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN (C = 1) THEN C ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN (D = 1) THEN D ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN (E = 1) THEN E ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN (F = 1) THEN F ELSE NULL END, CASE WHEN (G = 1) THEN G ELSE NULL END)

scala> df.select(col("*"),array(p1:_*).alias("panel")).withColumn("panel2",concat_ws(",",'panel)).show(false)
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----------------+-------+
|key|A  |B  |C  |D  |E  |F  |G  |panel           |panel2 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----------------+-------+
|s1 |0  |1  |0  |1  |1  |0  |1  |[, B,, D, E,, G]|B,D,E,G|
|s2 |1  |0  |0  |0  |0  |0  |0  |[A,,,,,,]       |A      |
|s3 |1  |1  |0  |0  |0  |0  |0  |[A, B,,,,,]     |A,B    |
|s4 |0  |1  |0  |1  |1  |0  |0  |[, B,, D, E,,]  |B,D,E  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----------------+-------+


scala>
```